# Working with multiple modules in Intellij IDEA Ultimate

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I want to create a single project containing an android module and a backend module.

Here's the steps I've made in attempt to do this:

1. Clone the backend repo into `/project/backend`.
2. Open a new project using the IDE from `/project`.
3. Setting `backend` as a project module.
4. Creating new android module from within the IDE.

The problem is after the last step - android folder structure and files are created but no module appears.

I would like to have one project with 2 modules (directories) each with its own settings.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you pls explain what `backend` means? ie is it an android/java project with already configured gradle ??

Comment: Sure, backend is a nodejs module containing my code for the backend of the project.

Comment: Just to clarify, what is your IDE ? Are you using `IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues opening the projects. So I `use FILE -> NEW -> IMPORT` to configure everything properly instead of `FILE -> OPEN`

1. Clone the backend repo into `/project/backend`.
2. Create a new project using the IDE in a separate folder `/newproject`.
3. Import project module from `/project/backend`
4. Create new `android` module using the IDE.

Comment: I've had issues in Step 3, when I use OPEN. Instead I always use IMPORT.